# Cannot Locate my Module from another folder n python

Tags: python

I've the following structure in my simple python project:

```
MainFolder
|
├───authentication
│   └───apikey.py
|   └───tokengenerator.py
├───Functions
│   └───generatedata.py
```

The `tokengenerator.py` module produces `Token` variables and I need to call it in `generatedata.py`module and I used the following code line for this purpose:

```py
from authentication.tokengenerator import Token
```

but it returns the error below:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'authentication'
```

Would you please advise ?

Comment: remove the `.py` for one. But you need to specify the MainFolder in your import: `from MainFolder.authentication.tokengenerator import Token`

Comment: @EdoAkse sorry the py was a mistake. it doesnt work adding the MainFolder

Comment: see the section `Import a File in a Different Directory` in [this article](https://csatlas.com/python-import-file-module/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [this article](https://csatlas.com/python-import-file-module/), you can add the path *below* the Functions folder to the searchpath for modules by adding `..` (combined with the scriptpath)

```py
import os
import sys

script_dir = os.path.dirname( __file__ )
mymodule_dir = os.path.join( script_dir, '..')
sys.path.append( mymodule_dir )

from authentication.tokengenerator import Token
token = Token()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding an empty `__init__.py` file in the authentication and Functions folder.

Additionally, you may need to use:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))
```

before importing the modules.